# Laravel /images route to public/images isn't passing routes.web function for /images

Tags: laravel, apache

Someone alerted me about being able to browse all the images in public/images using the 'images'.

However this is only on our live server (shared host). The local xampp host sends me to a 403 complaining about lacking an index page, even though I don't know exactly know why (I suppose it's some Apache setting?).

When I simply tried adding function in routes.web for /routes (or /public/routes just to try it), it didn't work at all

```
Route::get('/images', function () {
    abort(404, __('errors.images-root-restricted'));
});
```

Now I know that the folders in the /public are a bit special, but I'd like to know what's going on here, and if there is a way to still stop the live server from generating an index page of folder contents.

An explanation on how xampp is blocking it but why the live server isn't would be appreciated as well.

Comment: where you have hosted your application? is you browser showing all files and folders listing?

Comment: It's just some internet shared host that offered laravel-ready packages. I chose for that option because I'm not very expienced with all the hosting stuff. If I go to mydomain.com/images i get the typical barebones index view with the folders and images files.

Comment: Make sure that you have htacces file in public folder.  htaccess should be enabled on hosting in apache settings and also directory listing should be disabled in in apache configuration file.